# Jenkins Configuration change

Tags: jenkins

How to change name of configuration in jenkins it is default . I want to change it to linux.

[image: I want to change default to lin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify axis to your Multi-Configuration Project; on the project configuration page click "Add axis":

[image]

Your choice here depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you wan't your build to run on a specific Slave/Agent or do you simply wan't to set an environment variables to different values? There is a summary of [different axis here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin).

But for simplicity sake, let's take user-defined axis, this will provide an environment variable which is set to the value provided:

[image]

In this case I've entered linux and windows and on the project view I get:

[image]

And each time I build the project it will run two instances of the project, one with platform equal to linux and one with platform equal to windows.